# How do I load two iframes from the same source on link click?

Tags: html, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to display the price list for the services on my website with iFrames pulled from Zoho Creator.
The problem I'm having is that one service has some products with prices available and some products with pricing on demand.

Those are two different iframes and both should be displayed when clicked on that service link. Since iFrame can take only one src attribute, how can I load two of them by clicking on the same link?

So far, I've created button links where each link has assigned unique class like

```
<a class="button radiology button_size_2 button_js" href="#radiologija"><span class="button_label">Radiology</span></a>
```

I have an element where the first iframe is being loaded on page load:

```
<iframe id="declinedframe" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://creator.zohopublic.com/example1" width="100%" height="585"></iframe>
```

and jQuery code that changes iframes depending on the link clicked

```
(function($) {

  $('.changeframe').click(function () {
    $('#declinedframe').attr('src', 'https://creator.zohopublic.com/example2');
  });
  $('.radiology').click(function () {
    $('#declinedframe').attr('src', 'https://creator.zohopublic.com/example3'); // for radiology I need to load two iframes
  });
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: How do you imagine this would work? You have ONE iFrame, then you can show ONE page. If you send the URLs of the iFrames to your server, you might be able to merge the results and show in one place, that does not even have to be an iFrame

Comment: You must use two `iframe`.

Comment: @mplungjan I imagined it to work in a way when clicking one link that tow iframes would open one below another.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(function() {
  $('.changeframe').click(function () {
    $('#declinedframe').attr('src', 'https://creator.zohopublic.com/example2');
  });
  $('#radiologija').click(function () {
    $('#declinedframe').attr('src', 'https://creator.zohopublic.com/example2'); 
    if ($("#container").find("iframe").length===1) {
      const if2 = $('<iframe />',{ "id":"if2" });
      $('#declinedframe').next().after(if2);
    }
    $('#if2').attr('src', 'https://creator.zohopublic.com/example3'); 
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button radiology button_size_2 button_js" href="#" id="radiologija"><span class="button_label">Radiology</span></a> 
<div id="container">
  <iframe id="declinedframe"></iframe><hr/>
</div>
```